# Не освобождается память у динамического массива строк char(char**)

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, char

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые.
Собственно...
Память не освобождается у массива tmp, вбрасывает исключение.
НО. Если не добавлять нулевой символ-терминал(а strcpy по-умолчанию его копирует), то всё удаляется корректно. Объясните пожалуйста, никак не могу найти, из-за чего такая проблема. Спасибо заранее. Код(всё из main, потребуются заголовки - всё приложу):

```
char* mas[9] = { "Psadasdasd","asdasdP","Pasdasd","Padas","Pasdasdadasdasd","Pasdasd","Pada","Pasda","asdP" };

char** tmp = new char*[10]; // новый массив
for (int i(0); i < 9; i++) // заполнение нового массива старыми значениями
{
    tmp[i] = new char[strlen(mas[i])];
    strcpy(tmp[i], mas[i]); // здесь есть завершающий символ. Из-за него память не может быть освобождена
}
for (int i(9); i < 10; i++) // одна новая строка
{
    tmp[i] = new char[10];
    tmp[i][0] = '\0';
}
for (int i(0); i < 10; i++)
    delete[] tmp[i];
delete [] tmp;
```

Comment: Для начала выделять надо не strlen байт, а на 1 больше, для завершающего 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам надо выделять память для нулевого символа строк. Например,

```
char** tmp = new char*[10]; // новый массив
for (int i(0); i < 9; i++) // заполнение нового массива старыми значениями
{
    tmp[i] = new char[strlen(mas[i]) + 1];
    strcpy(tmp[i], mas[i]); // здесь есть завершающий символ. Из-за него память не может быть освобождена
}
```

Кроме того у вас десятый элемент динамического массива не инициализирован. Если вы его хотите иметь как граничное значение, то код должен выглядеть как

```
char** tmp = new char*[10]; // новый массив
for (int i(0); i < 9; i++) // заполнение нового массива старыми значениями
{
    tmp[i] = new char[strlen(mas[i]) + 1];
    strcpy(tmp[i], mas[i]); // здесь есть завершающий символ. Из-за него память не может быть освобождена
}
tmp[9] = nullptr;
```

Тогда бы вы могли удалить выделенные динамически массивы как

```
for (int i(0); i < 10; i++)
    delete[] tmp[i];
delete [] tmp;
```

Различие первого цикла с этим циклом

```
for (int i(9); i < 10; i++) // одна новая строка
{
    tmp[i] = new char[10];
    tmp[i][0] = '\0';
}
```

состоит в том, что все 10 элементов массива были инициализированы, тогда как в первом цикле, если не добавить предложение, как я указал

```
tmp[9] = nullptr;
```

инициализируются только 9 элементов массива. Последний элемент не инициализирован. Поэтому программа имеет неопределенное поведение.

Для второго цикла, когда все 10 элементов инициализируется, в этом предложении

```
    tmp[i][0] = '\0';
```

нет никакого смысла в контексте удаления массивов. Вы можете написать просто

```
for (int i(9); i < 10; i++) // одна новая строка
{
    tmp[i] = new char[10];
}
```

Разве что предложение

```
    tmp[i][0] = '\0';
```

вам нужно лишь для того, чтобы последний элемент массива хранил пустую строку.

Comment: <<нужно лишь для того, чтобы последний элемент массива хранил пустую строку.
Всё верно. Строка заполняется позже, и удаление происходит позже. С окончанием строки теперь все работает:)

Answer (score 3):

```
tmp[i] = new char[strlen(mas[i])];  // Выделили памяти ровно столько,
                                    //сколько символов - БЕЗ НУЛЕВОГО
strcpy(tmp[i], mas[i]);  // Копируете С НУЛЕВЫМ
```

Что вы еще хотите?...

Comment: Спасибо, вопрос решён. Виноват.